Как оформлять текст в ботах Telegram?
Нужно как-то оформлять текст, который отправляет бот - жирный, моно и другие. У меня почему-то не проходят знаки *, ` и другие, текст обычным получается, даже \n в виде новой строки не хочет. Как сделать?

Используёте не markdown, а html. https://docs.leadconverter.su/faq/populyarnye-voprosy/telegram/kak-oformit-tekst-v-telegram

чистов_n, ничего не работает.

Нужно установить parse_mode, и использовать HTML разметку для форматирования текста тут больше информации. Но еще можно использовать Markdown разметку, указав в parse_mode - MarkdownV2.
Если вы используете aiogram, то добавьте это в бота:
from aiogram.client.defaul import DefaultBotProperties
from aiogram import Dispatcher, Bot
from aiogram.types import Message

import asyncio

bot = Bot(default=DefaultBotProperties(parse_mode="HTML"))
dp = Dispatcher()

@dp.message()
async def on_message(message: Message):
    await message.answer(f"<b>{message.text}</b>")

asyncio.run(dp.start_polling(bot))

